# createStatement SQL ResultSet next() is returning false

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper, resultset

I keep test this connection `ResultSet` and while `System.out.println(rs)` returns a `oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@2aa5fe93`

`System.out.println(rs.next())` gives me false

and my output is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.prjzr.Driver.main(Driver.java:31)
```

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    public List<User> getUser() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM USERPROFILE";

        try(Connection conn = DatabaseAccessUtil.getHardCodedConnection(); 
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);){

        //  System.out.println(rs);
        while(rs.next()) {

            int recNumber = rs.getInt("RECNUMBER");
            String username = rs.getString("USERID");
            String acctHldrFirstName = rs.getString("ACCOUNTHOLDERFIRSTNAME");
            String acctHldrFirstLast = rs.getString("ACCOUNTHOLDERLASTNAME");
            String acctHldrMailing = rs.getString("ACOUNTHOLDERMAILING");
            String primaryAcctKey = rs.getString("PRIMARYACCTNUMBER");
            String userPassword = rs.getString("PASSWORD");
            users.add(new User(recNumber, username,  acctHldrFirstName, acctHldrFirstLast, acctHldrMailing, primaryAcctKey, userPassword));

        }


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I've look at other question and their issue is slightly different than this one.
How do a read my records and get rid of the

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.prjzr.Driver.main(Driver.java:31)
```

Comment: Why are your returning `null`?  Shouldn't you be returning `list`?   The NPE is probably happening because you are trying to use the `null`.

Comment: If `rs.next()` returns `false`, that means that all results have been consumed.

Comment: This method returns `null`, and you can also print something in the `while` loop so that you can see whether `rs.next` always returns `false`.

Comment: It was the null return but when I change the null to users I get back blanks

Comment: Yep that was it after I commit on sql everything was Roger!